# jQuery click effect

Tags: jquery

Hi everyone I am currently designing a button that changes to another image when the user hovers over it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","button-hover.png");
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","button.png");
    });
});
```

I was just wondering how would I add a third "click" feature i.e. when the user clicks on the image it changes to another image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bind to the `click` event as well?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` can be written `$(function(){`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $(".button").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","button-hover.png");
            }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","button.png");
    }).click(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","button-click.png");
    });
});
```

Assuming you want your button to change images when clicked, like you do upon hover. Also assuming you have a file called `button-click.png`.

Comment: There's no need to reuse the `.button` selector since `hover` can be chained, like the majority of jQuery methods.

Comment: Chaining. Still haven't gotten into the habit of using it. Editing to fix that, thanks.

Comment: No problem. It's a good thing to get into the habit of. It's far more efficient, especially if you're using more complex selectors. An alternative is to store the result of the selector in a variable and reuse that every time instead. +1.

Comment: fyi, If you do store in a variable, convention says to prefix the variable with $ so you know its a jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem.  Here's your code with mine added.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","button-hover.png");
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","button.png");
    });

    //added click function below
    $(".button").click(function() {
        //do click actions here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('div.search').click(
    function(){ 
      return false; //depend on you return true or false the event is propagated
    }
);